# Dual boot ubuntu 14 &16. uninstall 16 and reinstall?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I dual boot my ubuntu 14.04 with ubuntu 16.04. Seeing if I liked the upgraded version. After the installation the 16.04 has errors and needs to be taken down. It won't install some programs, especially 3rd party and it can't identify software list, red error icon appearer in the top bar. I'd like to reinstall 16.04 so I can evaluate the upgrade. I have atom text editor and developing my own web pages in the 14.04 installation and would like to keep if I can. I want to try and not format but if I have to I'll save my work on the bac up drive on my home network router. Does anyone have other options I could try. Will appreciate all the help I get.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot your 14.04 installation and mount the drives from the 16.04 install to recover your files. Then I would just reinstall 16.04.